# Docker overlay networks prevent IP forwarding

Tags: docker, routes, ip, overlay, iptables

When utilizing Overlay networks in docker, the docker engine takes care of relevant iptables rules.

I have 5 containers. 4 of them are apps and 1 of them is a "gateway", which i would like all traffic to go through this gateway (Ip_forwarding container)

with --link this worked perfectly, but with overlay network this seems to be prevented due to the iptables rules.

Any assistance would be appreciate on a recommended method to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone might reach this issue ever again.
It was a routing issue, if you ever come across this issue do the following:
1. Disable FW.
2. Use tcpdump to determine which route the packets arrive to / from.
3. use ip route get to determine out going routes.